# How can I obtain only the LinkedIn followers from my company

Tags: linkedin-api

Can you help me? I am using the following code, but with this code, I get the followers of my company and an additional button from LinkedIn. However, I only want to display the followers and not an extra button. I want to purchase a physical counter, but I need a JavaScript script for this that only displays the followers without additional functionality. Can someone assist me with this?

`<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script> <script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="0000" data-counter="bottom"></script>`